# Localized NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

With help from some answered questions from others here I managed to get my NSDateFormatter working with strings in a different locale. Currently my code is the following:

```
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
//myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init]; --- unnecesary as marked by @rmaddy
myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@ ==== %@",dateString, myDate);
```

Giving me the following result in console:

```
Nov 11, 2011 11:11:00 AM ==== 2011-11-10 23:11:00 +0000
Feb 22, 2222 10:22:00 PM ==== 2222-02-22 11:22:00 +0000
Dec 12, 2012 12:12:00 PM ==== 2012-12-12 11:12:00 +0000
Dec 22, 2012 10:22:00 PM ==== 2012-12-22 11:22:00 +0000
```

Hopefully I'm just overlooking something simple, but I can't see where I'm wrong and why its changing 10:22 PM into 11:22 +0000 or 11:11 AM into 23:11

Comment: Isn't there daylight saving time in your locale settings?

Comment: FYI - Why do you needlessly create and throw away the `NSDate` instance? The line `myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];` is unnecessary.

Comment: @rmaddy - true, result of copying and pasting and not cleaning up... removed the line! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format for 24 hours (uppercase H), just change it to use 12 hours (lowercase h):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"]
```

You can find date format patters [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: sigh. I overlooked the uppercase. Thanks a lot, that just saved me quite some time!  will accept answer as soon as I'm allowed ;)